# Redux - how does combineReducers know which subset of the app state to pass to the reducer

Tags: javascript, redux

In the [Redux basics tutorial](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html) section on Reducers I can't quite understand how the following syntax deduces which subset of the app state to pass to each reducer referenced in the call to combineReducers. Is it purely matching the state member name on the reducer name?

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { ADD_TODO, COMPLETE_TODO, SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER, VisibilityFilters } from './actions'
const { SHOW_ALL } = VisibilityFilters

function visibilityFilter(state = SHOW_ALL, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER:
      return action.filter
    default:
      return state
  }
}

function todos(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TODO:
      return [
        ...state,
        {
          text: action.text,
          completed: false
        }
      ]
    case COMPLETE_TODO:
      return state.map((todo, index) => {
        if (index === action.index) {
          return Object.assign({}, todo, {
            completed: true
          })
        }
        return todo
      })
    default:
      return state
  }
}

const todoApp = combineReducers({
  visibilityFilter,
  todos
})

export default todoApp
```

Comment: That code doesn't. You have to specify that inside of the components themselves.

Comment: Correct.  I think if it wasn't using the new ES6 syntax it would be more obvious.

combineReducers({
  todos: myTodoReducer
})

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding your specific question about how this works with the `combineReducers` function, just check out the source code. You can see in [combineReducers.js in the redux repo](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/src/combineReducers.js#L128-129) that as the action goes through every reducer that's been combined, each individual reducer gets passed the branch of state that matches its corresponding key in the object you pass to `combineReducers`.

So in your example, both the `visibilityFilter` and `todos` reducers have keys of the same name (because of the [ES6 object property shorthand](http://es6-features.org/#PropertyShorthand) you're using). And those keys are what are used to pass the specific branches of state to each respective reducer.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted is simply 2 reducers, their actual application cannot be seen in there.

Take into perspective the following code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { addTodo } from '../actions'

let AddTodo = ({ dispatch }) => {
  let input

  return (
    <div>
      <input ref={node => {
        input = node
      }} />
      <button onClick={() => {
        dispatch(addTodo(input.value))
        input.value = ''
      }}>
        Add Todo
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}
AddTodo = connect()(AddTodo)

export default AddTodo
```

When the components button is clicked, it fires off an action (`addTodo`):

```
const addTodo = (text) => {
  return {
    type: 'ADD_TODO',
    id: nextTodoId++,
    text
  }
}
```

Which is then processed by one of the reducers you posted above:

```
const todo = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_TODO':
      return {
        id: action.id,
        text: action.text,
        completed: false
      }
    case 'TOGGLE_TODO':
      if (state.id !== action.id) {
        return state
      }

      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        completed: !state.completed
      })

    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Which then deduces the next state of the application and returns that as the brand new state. State is passed to the reducer by the dispatcher.

Note: All code above was taken from the same tutorial OP posted.